# записать данные в одну таблицу из нескольких таблиц одним запросом

Tags: sql

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли заполнить пустую таблицу данными из 3-х других таблиц одним запросом. Например можно из одной таблицы переписать в другую таким запросом:

```
INSERT INTO table1 AS t1 (id, firstname, lastname, age) VALUES
SELECT t2.id,
t2.firstname,
t2.lastname,
t2.age
FROM table2 AS t2
```

Но если есть еще 2 таблицы с такими же названиями столбцов и их нужно тоже записать в table1 но с разными id, т.к. он уникален. Как можно поступить?

Comment: *Как можно поступить?* Обычно `id` - это первичный автоинкрементный индекс. Соответственно присвоение ему значений обычно не требуется, и это поле вообще не присутствует в запросе (ни в INSERT, ни в SELECT).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться оператором UNION.
То есть вы из трех таблиц собираете одну и эти значения даете Insert.
http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_union.html

```
INSERT INTO table1 AS t1 (id, firstname, lastname, age) VALUES
SELECT // а тут Union
```

Comment: Спасибо! А поле  id возможно генерировать уникальный на случай если в 3-х таблицах они повторяются?

Comment: если повторяются, то делаете в table1 его автоинкрементом, а вставляете-выбираете все оставшиеся поля кроме id. Чистый юнион уберет дубли, если что.

Comment: `values` тут не нужно, кстати

Comment: если нужно какую то связь с ID старыми сохранить, то условно можно сделать `select 1000000 + id from t1 union select 2000000 + id from t2` в общм разнести их в разные неперекрывающиеся диапазоны

Comment: Спасибо! Так и сделаю